# .htaccess RewriteEngine for making one alias and redirecting all other routers to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use this for redirecting all calls to index.php (using Slim framework here):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Now because I don't want to store files inside my public folder, but somewhere else (and still access them from domain.com/files). I found out that this does what I need:

```
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ ../share/files/$1
```

But how to combine those two into one?..

Comment: Does this rule `RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ ../share/files/$1` work independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place your new rule before the other one (and don't forget to add the stoping flag L):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ ../share/files/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. If you have a chance, could you please explain a bit about this code and flags.

Comment: You welcome. The htaccess file is analyzed from top to bottom, as if a request comes, the first rule that matches the request gets executed, if you add the L flag, the analyzing exits it that rule, if you don't add it, the analyzing continues to find other rules.